# Posix timer functions on windows (timer_t, timer_create, timer_start)

Tags: mingw, posix, librt

Is it possible to compile code, using mingw64, that uses librt functionality?
The functions needed a listed below.
I am struggling to find any information to that question.

```
 int timer_create(clockid_t clockId, struct sigevent *evp, timer_t *timerid);

 int timer_delete(timer_t timerid);
```

Thanks for your help,
Nico